# VS Code not printing output

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, runner

I don't get an output,  please help me out

[image]

I'm new to python and VS Code, I've installed python and code runner, but I can't still print an output, it executed the code with no error but not printing on the console.

Comment: Don't look under "Output". Look under "Terminal".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the code runner extension. You have to disable the code runner.

Click `Ctrl+Shift+X` to launch **Extensions**.
Search **Code Runner** and click **Disable**.
Close the VSCode editor and reopen it. Now run the program.
You will get the output.